# Get data from the current authenticated user in ASP.NET/Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have this ApplicationUser class

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace BbcSrUI.Data.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public bool EnableNewCall { get; set; }
        public bool EnableNewEvent { get; set; }
        public bool EnableCalls { get; set; }
        public bool EnableEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to access to the BrandId data of the authenticated user in the index page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently also working with the same sort of system. This is my approach on getting the "ApplicationUser" info from the authenticated user.
To start off, I have this function.

```cs
        [CascadingParameter]
        private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
        [CascadingParameter]
        public AuthenticationState AuthenticationState { get; set; }

        public async Task<Guid> GetUserId()
        {
            AuthenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;

            string Id =
            AuthenticationState.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            return Guid.Parse(Id);

        }
```

This function returns the ID of the currently authenticated user.
Now, in my project, I have a `UserService` setup. So I can easily call:

```cs
ApplicationUser user = await userService.GetUserByIdAsync(await GetUserID);
```

Which that point I had access to all the information about the currently logged-in user.

```cs
AuthorName = user.FullName;
AuthorPhone = user.PhoneNumber;
AuthorEmail = user.Email;
```

I'm not sure how ur project is set up, but I reckon it would usually also look like this. If you have any question, just ask!